# Babel 7 + react + redux => crash on IE / old FF

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, react-router, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I got a problem with `react-redux` and ie (targeted 11).

```
Project with : 
>     "react": "^16.5.1",
>     "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
>     "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
>     "redux": "^4.0.0",
>     "@babel/XXX" : ^7.0.0
```

with babel and got polyfill :

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": "> 0.25%, not dead",
          "useBuiltIns": "entry"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "react-hot-loader/babel",
      "lodash",
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        {
          "legacy": true
        }
      ],
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  }
```

code example :

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Test extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        the anwser is : {this.props.test}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// with or without compose there is the same result
export default compose (
  connect(
    (state) => ({
      test: 42
    }),{
    })
) (Test);
```

In chrome, I get: "the answer is: 42"

In IE11: blank page ... / Collator could not be initialized and wouldn't be used

In firefox 45:
[react-router provider error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLByE.png)
[another error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X67Ql.png)

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to add `bowserslist` field to `package.json` and add `@babel/polyfill` as a dependency.
This tells babel-preset-env and @babel/polyfill to compile with compatibility to values specified in browserlist.

Example (pacakge.json):

```
{
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "maintained node versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Note that you'll need to use babel preset env for this to work.

Comment: i already had `'@babel/polyfill'` in my config webpack and i use https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env docs, they said targets in options but bowserslist too

Comment: You can have browserlist in env options as well. I find it  useful to add it in package.json because other tools can you this field.

Comment: So where i have to add this browserlist field ? In babel.presets."@babel/preset-env" or like babel / name level ?

Comment: In package.json. Make sure to adjust the browsers according to your needs. If you target more old browsers then you need your bundle might size grow

Comment: but  there crash in ie11 with this browserlist field

Comment: I seems like your app has runtime errors on IE that have something to do with polyfills. Can you add the IE error image? It would help a lot.

Comment: this is an error but not in react itself, it's on runtime with redux-saga now, redux saga doesn't display error ... I add some error in the main topic

Comment: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga#using-umd-build-in-the-browser
In this link it explains that you have to polyfill generators.With this: https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/tree/master/packages/regenerator-transform

Comment: Install `regenerator-transform` with npm. Add this to your babel config plugins: `"plugins": [
    ["regenerator-transform", {
      asyncGenerators: false, // true by default
      generators: false, // true by default
      async: false // true by default
    }]
  ]`

Comment: in production mode i got a new error ( i upload image on man topic )

Comment: that's a syntax error in 'for in' loop. If the initial error went away this problem was solved.